# How to work with background application?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created an app that triggers video at particular time similar to alarm, but the problem I am facing is that when I am out of application & have set the timings the video doesn't show up(i.e. similar to alarm I should get notification out side my app). Please help me out with the same. Would be very grateful for any helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an application is not running, you cannot predict what time its background process will execute, so there is no way that you can set an alarm with any degree of precision smaller than perhaps an hour.  The only way to have timing close to accurate would be with a push notification from a server.  Even then, the notification you receive will not be able to open and play video on its own.  You could create a push/toast notification that originates at a server, sends the user a toast, the user taps it, and that opens the app to play the video.  You can't do it without user intervention.

See this link for an overview, including the constraints on background agents: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942(v=VS.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open an app and play a video from a background agent. You can show a toast notification that would allow the user to open the app. You can use a [Scheduled Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202965%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) or [PeriodicTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).You can then use the [ShellToast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.shelltoast%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to show a toast notification so the user can open the app. Once the app is open you can start the video.